# Generate brackets with steps of 10 from an array and eliminate empty steps

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json

I'm having trouble solving this problem:

I have an array of objects:

```
tableList = [
{table_number: 1},
{table_number: 11},
{table_number: 31}
]
```

I'm trying to generate a bracket list in steps of 10 up to the largest 'table_number'.

I'm using a sequence generator function for this:

```
// Sequence generator function (commonly referred to as "range", e.g. Clojure, PHP etc)
const range = (start, stop, step) => Array.from({ length: (stop - start) / step + 1}, (_, i) => start + (i * step));
```

I'm using Math.max and iterate through the array to find the biggest 'table_number':

```
// Search for biggest table number
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(o => o.table_number));
```

I then generate the bracket array with the sequencing function:

```
// Generate brackets up until biggest table number
var brackets = range(0, max, 10);
```

This gives me a bracket array of [0, 10, 20, 30].

Now the question is, how do I evaluate the array of objects to remove the empty bracket step (20) that will not contain any 'table_number'?

Or should I be generating the bracket array differently?

I would really appreciate any help for this, thanks!

Comment: Is this what you're after? const tableNumbers = tableList.map((table) => table.table_number -1); Or do I misunderstand the intended outcome?

Comment: Expected output ? `[0, 10, 30]` ?

Comment: I need to dedupe the numbers if have say an array of table numbers of [1, 7, 11, 12, 17, 22, 26], I have found to solution to be: const brackets = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.table_number - (item.table_number % 10)))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles on this, I have found this to be my solution.

```
const brackets = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.table_number - (item.table_number % 10)))]
```

I visit each element in the object and then subtract from it's remainder to get the numbers in steps of 10.

I then create a Set object from the outcome, effectively removing all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

> Or should I be generating the bracket array differently?

If you're just after an array like `[0,10,30]` you can follow a different path:

```js
tableList = [
{table_number: 1},
{table_number: 11},
{table_number: 31}
]


const tmpObj = tableList.reduce( (acc,cur) => {
  acc[ Math.floor(cur.table_number/10)*10 ] = true;
  return acc;
} , {})

const brackets = Object.keys(tmpObj).map((x) => parseInt(x));
console.log(brackets);
```

But this is taking advantage of how easy is "in steps of 10"